# Graph API URL's intermittently returning bad URL (java http response code 400)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

So I am writing a program that runs through a list of Facebook user's URLs already provided and then accesses their graph API. So user facebook.com/josh.maddock.7 accesses graph.facebook/com/josh.maddock.7 .

Unfortunately, the program is randomly picking a time to stop working and decides that every URL it receives form that point on is invalid and returns http response code 400. For example, one time it will access the graph information correctly for 1500 users, and when it is run immediately after, it only works for 500. Even though the URLs are fine and it may have worked fine for the execution directly before or after, it still returns these errors.

It sleeps for 50 seconds after every 500 users, as this first seemed to help the problem but obviously not well enough. (I tried sleeping for up to 5 min and still had this problem.)

Does anyone know why it may be doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error message?